# UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL always nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to pick a video from PhotoAlbum. I'm using the `UIImagePickerController` but every time after i chose the video `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` is returning `nil`.

What I am missing?

Thanks.

```
    - (IBAction)galerry:(id)sender {

    self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [self.imagePickerController setDelegate:self];

    self.imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    self.imagePickerController.mediaTypes =@[(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo];
    [self.imagePickerController setVideoMaximumDuration:20];
    self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];


}





- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSURL *videoURL= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSString *moviePath = [videoUrl path];

    NSURL *imagePickerURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]; 

     NSURL *videoURL2= [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata];


//    picker.videoQuality=UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        Edition *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditionVC"];
        vc.videoUrl=videoURL;
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }];



}
```

All variables returning `nil` (videoURL,videoUrl,imagePickerURL,videoURL2). 
What is wrong here?

EDIT:

This is my info dictionary:

```
    po info
{
    UIImagePickerControllerMediaType = "public.movie";
    UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL = "assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=87B8D3F5-DE9C-4F06-A88B-5116055A618A&ext=MOV";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>    

- (void)getVideo {
      UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
      imagePicker.delegate = self;
      imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
      imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[ (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie ];

      [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
      NSString *mediaType = info[ UIImagePickerControllerMediaType ];

      if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
          NSURL *videoUrl=(NSURL*) info[ UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL ];
          NSString *moviePath = [videoUrl path];

          if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath)) {
              UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum (moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
          }
       }

      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: videoUrl & moviePath =nil

Comment: FYI, it seems that UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL is not returned anymore when you link against the iOS 9 SDK.

Comment: @Marc-AlexandreBérubé you are right. Best solution is to check both values, prioritizing `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` :
`NSURL *assetUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] ?: info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];`